# Method Reference to private constructor throws IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, android, android-multidex, method-reference, dexguard

Edit:  Thanks for the commenters trying to repro!  It's starting to look like this is an issue with Dexguard specifically. this may be related to [DexGuard integration in Android Studio 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979056/dexguard-integration-in-android-studio-3-0).

So I'm running into an odd error when trying to pass a private constructor of an object as a method reference to a Supplier of the same type. I was able to boil it down to:

```
public class Test {    
    public static final Supplier<Test> supplier = Test::new;
    private Test() {}
}
```

When trying to invoke `Test.supplier.get()`, I get a crash and the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void myapp.Test.()' is inaccessible to class 'myapp.Test$$Lambda$1' (declaration of 'myapp.Test$$Lambda$1' appears in /data/app/myapp-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)

Note that this only seems to happen for constructors:  doing the following worked as expected.

```
public class Test {
    public final Supplier<String> stringSupplier = this::buildString;
    private String buildString() { return "hi!"; }
}
```

works fine when invoking `new Test().stringSupplier.get()` from outside the class.

Meanwhile, using a lambda instead of a method reference also works without crashing for private constructors (`() -> new Test()` instead of `Test::new`)

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could be a bug that’s only affecting some versions. I just tried using jdk1.8.0_65 and no exception was thrown.

Comment: Could not reproduce in Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Could not reproduce with IntelliJ 2017.2.5 (and Java 1.8.0_151).

Comment: Thanks for trying to repro folks!  Did any of you happen to have multidex enabled?  I tried a couple different JDK's with no result

Comment: The second should work fine, since the lambda will be executing in the class escope and will have access to the private constructor.
The first one if is invoked by reflection probably will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug, please report it to support@guardsquare.com and it can be fixed quite fast.

Comment: The next version of DexGuard 8.1.08 will include a fix for this.